# Configure react-native-wifi-reborn in iOS

Tags: ios, react-native

I want to configure reac-native-wifi-reborn library in iOS. I have to follow two steps but I do not know where to start. I do not know how to enable Access WIFI information and any of the steps that follow. There are all in https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-wifi-reborn

'
iOS

You need use enable Access WIFI Information, with correct profile. Hotspot Configuration is required in order to connect to networks.

iOS 13

You need put "Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description" or "Privacy - Location Always and When In Use Usage Description" in Settings -> info'

I want to to configure it in iOS 13.